# java vm 32 on ubuntu 64

Tags: 12.04, java, jvm

This is a problem,

A school project is to make a midlet with java micro edition
I have dowloaded java wireless tool kit below

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#sun_java_wireless_toolkit-2.5.2_01b-oth-JPR

when i run midlet project I get error below:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/nikola/faks/CS230/WTK2.5.2_ML/bin/sublime.so: /home/nikola/faks/CS230/WTK2.5.2_ML/bin/sublime.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
at com.sun.kvem.Sublime.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at com.sun.kvem.Lime.createLime(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.kvem.KVMBridge.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.kvem.KVMBridge.getBridge(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.kvem.midp.MIDP.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.kvem.environment.EmulatorInvoker.runEmulatorImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.kvem.environment.EmulatorInvoker.main(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.kvem.environment.JVM.main(Unknown Source)
```

Question is ,A 64-Bit Ubuntu can run 32-Bit a Java Virtual Machine(JVM)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the `ia32-libs` package from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: that is already installed

Comment: I found [this solution](http://www.bozaro.ru/2010/07/21/wtk_64bit_linux/) (on russian language). Maybe this article will help.